# Use the output of one query to execute another query in Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am executing query in Mongo shell and require the output of this query to execute the second query. The first query is the aggregate query to find the average.

The first query is :

```
db.table_name.aggregate([{$group: {_id:{userId:'$userId'},avgRating:{$avg:"$rating"}}}])
```

Now using the `_id (userId)` in the output, I wanna fetch the data from user table.

Comment: May we see your queries, edited into the question, and formatted nicely? I have trimmed out material from your question that is not directly relevant, and please do note [that requesting urgency is not well-received here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: Do you want to query two different table simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for another query, you can still run the same aggregate operation but this time adding another pipeline that uses the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator which pipes the results from the previous **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to do a left join on the `user` collection:

```
db.table_name.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
            "avgRating": { "$avg": "$rating" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "user",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "users"
        }
    }
])
```

---

If your MongoDB version does not support the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator, then you will need two queries, run as follows:

```
var cursor = db.table_name.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
            "avgRating": { "$avg": "$rating" }
        }
    }
]);

var results = cursor.map(function(doc){ 
    var user = db.users.findOne({ "_id": doc._id })
    return {
        user: user,
        avgRating: doc.avgRating
    }; 
});
printjson(results);
```